# poisson random variable + conditional probability

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-probability, poisson-distribution

Let Y be the number of calls to a particular hotline within 10 min. Suppose Y is a Poisson random variable with mean of 3. Find the probability that there are at most 4 calls given that there are already 2 calls within the 10 min.

I'm not really sure how to go about solving this. Am I supposed to be looking at this in terms of a binomial random variable? If not, then how would I set up the conditional probability?

Answer (score 0):

By definition of conditional probability,
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(Y\leqslant 4\mid Y\geqslant 2) &= \mathbb P(Y=2\mid Y\geqslant 2) + \mathbb P(Y=3\mid Y\geqslant 2) + \mathbb P(Y=4\mid Y\geqslant 2)\\
&= \frac{\mathbb P(Y=2,Y\geqslant 2)}{\mathbb P(Y\geqslant 2)} +\frac{\mathbb P(Y=3,Y\geqslant 2)}{\mathbb P(Y\geqslant 2)} +\frac{\mathbb P(Y=4,Y\geqslant 2)}{\mathbb P(Y\geqslant 2)}\\
&= \frac{\mathbb P(Y=2)+\mathbb P(Y=3)+\mathbb P(Y=4)}{1 - (\mathbb P(Y=0) + \mathbb P(Y=1))}\\
&= \frac{e^{-3}(3^2/2! + 3^3/3! + 3^4/4!)}{1 - e^{-3}(1 + 3)}\\
&\approx 0.7693246.
\end{align}

Comment: Why is it Y>=2 and not Y=2?

Comment: From the wording of the question, it's given that there were at least two calls in the first $10$ minutes.